# Use VBA to map data recorded in individual rows to output into a mapped format for system interface

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset of around 9000 lines which I am trying to map into a specific format in order to interface this information into an Information Management system. The data is currently held as below:

| EmpID | PostID | PostSTARTDATE | INDICATOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | A2 | A3 |
| B | B1 | B2 | B3 |
| C | C1 | C2 | C3 |
| D | D1 | D2 | D3 |

and needs to output as below for each line:

| BLANK | BLANK | BLANK | BLANK | BLANK | BLANK | BLANK | BLANK | BLANK | BLANK | BLANK | BLANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00EMPLOYEE | 1 | A | blank | blank | N | blank | blank | blank | blank | blank | blank |
| 80POST | 1 | A | blank | blank | A1 | A2 | blank | blank | blank | blank | A3 |
| 00EMPLOYEE | 2 | B | blank | blank | N | blank | blank | blank | blank | blank | blank |
| 80POST | 2 | B | blank | blank | B1 | B2 | blank | blank | blank | blank | B3 |
| 00EMPLOYEE | 3 | C | blank | blank | N | blank | blank | blank | blank | blank | blank |
| 80POST | 3 | C | blank | blank | C1 | C2 | blank | blank | blank | blank | C3 |
| 00EMPLOYEE | 4 | D | blank | blank | N | blank | blank | blank | blank | blank | blank |
| 80POST | 4 | D | blank | blank | D1 | D2 | blank | blank | blank | blank | D3 |

The code needs to be able to go through the entire dataset and map it to another sheet in the above format, 00EMPLOYEE and 80POST must always be the first items in each row and must generate together procedurally. The number next to that column must generate as a transaction ID shared by both lines.

I hope this is enough information to go off as a starting point.

I have tried various lines of VBA but haven't managed to achieve anything so far.

Comment: Can you share your VBA code?

Comment: I don't have it unfortunately, quite new to this and didn't save it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill an array and write to sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Remap()

    Dim wb As Workbook, arIn, arOut
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    ' input
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    With wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        arIn = .Range("A2:D" & lastrow)
        ReDim arOut(1 To UBound(arIn) * 2, 1 To 12)
    End With
    
    ' remap
    For i = 1 To UBound(arIn)
        j = i * 2
        arOut(j - 1, 1) = "OOEMPLOYEE"
        arOut(j - 1, 2) = i
        arOut(j - 1, 3) = arIn(i, 1)
        arOut(j - 1, 6) = "N"
        
        arOut(j, 1) = "80POST"
        arOut(j, 2) = i
        arOut(j, 3) = arIn(i, 1)
        arOut(j, 6) = arIn(i, 2)
        arOut(j, 7) = arIn(i, 3)
        arOut(j, 12) = arIn(i, 4)
    Next
    
    ' output
    With wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arOut), 12) = arOut
    End With

    MsgBox lastrow - 1 & " rows mapped", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
End Sub
```